# How to interpolate the d attribute of an SVG path in React Active to use it for animation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, svg

I want to have a button in my React Native project, which should open a modal popup on click. However, I would like the modal to be of the same "material" as the button and opens with a fluid animation where the button becomes the modal. I created the SVG path's `d` attributes, resulting in the following two states of the `path`:

---

[image]

**TRY 1**

Now I add an `Animated` API animation, but unfortunately, nothing happens and I guess it is just because there is nothing to interpolate with as the `d` attribute is a string, but I need a number that can be interpolated somehow.

**TRY 2**

So another try of mine was to create the circle's path with the same amount of vertices as the modal path and then use the coordinates values to interpolate. However, I am using Inkscape to export the SVG's, but the resulting `d` attribute of the circle does not match with the modal one in terms of not having same SVG commands (e.g. such as vertical line `v` or bezier curve `s`).

**Question**

So I would be happy if anybody knows a way of animating an SVG path in the way described. Be it by using a library that I missed until now or by manipulating the SVG in a way that I can use it to interpolate the values with the React Native `Animated` API.

Comment: I guess you'd need to write an interpolation engine like the browsers have. You could [start from here](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/svg/SVGPathSegListSMILType.cpp)

Comment: In order to get the same SVG commands you can transform all the commands to C

Comment: @enxaneta How can I do that? Is there a tool? And as I understand it, the `C` would not result in curves, but only straight lines (or I need a large number of coordinates that imitate a curve)